# Vim: reformat CSS from one-line to multi-line rules

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, formatting

I wanted to reformat the [W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css) file to make it more readable and study it.

I looked for an easy way to do this but couldn't find it (in **vim-only way**, obviously, the web are plenty of solutions and software).
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22865673/6266107), but in my case the result is rather disappointing.

So I refreshed my notions of substitution in Vim and I did it as follows:

###### 1.  For each rule I break it in rows and put all properties in one line:

```
:%s/\(.\{-}{\)\(.\{-}\)\(}\)/\1\r\t\2\r\3\r/gc
```

Then this:

```css
1| html,body{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:1.5}html{overflow-x:hidden}
```

become:

```css
1| html,body{
2|     font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:1.5
3| }
4| html{
5|     overflow-x:hidden
6| }
7|
```

*Note the blank row at the end. I want it because there's multiple consistent rules per line.*

###### 2. Split properties one per line:

```
%s/;/;\r\t/gc
```

Then I get what I wanted:

```css
1| html,body{
2|     font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
3|     font-size:15px;
4|     line-height:1.5
5| }
6| html{
7|     overflow-x:hidden
8| }
9|
```

The difficulties come from the fact that:

1. There are multiple rules per row, such as those for headers, or those for tables, etc. In the example above there's two rules for html.
2. In the declaration block the last declaration is not terminated by a semicolon.

For this I needed two commands.

Who can do better? Is it possible to do everything with a **single substitution**?

Comment: Why would you do that when you can run %! css-beautify or %! prettier --parser css? If you need to do this often, `set formatprg=prettier\ --parser\ css` and run it with `gq<motion>` or via visual mode. Remember that vim was designed to work well with other unix tools (e.g. makeprg, grepprg, equalprg, formatprg, keywordprg and so on)

Comment: Because on Windows (at work) I don't have all this stuff, and if there exists often I can't arbitrarily install software.
Also, Vim is a powerful tool and should allow me to work with text very efficiently (I know that in pipes to AWK or Perl I can do great things with little effort but, as I said before, sometimes these tools are not available).

Comment: And, last but not least, I really enjoy learning new things, finding out how to accomplish a task in multiple ways and evaluating its efficiency, in short, a little bit of healthy hacking never hurts. If we don't do it here, in a group about Vim,.. ;-)

Comment: That's fair, however, in this case, formatting based on substitutions is really prone to errors. It is good to know many solutions for a single problem, as long as all of them are good, reasonably equivalent solutions. Having said that, if it is just for fun, then that's okay ;)

Comment: @r_31415 Yeah `prettier` is what should be used here, I came here to say that. If you post that as an answer I'll definitely upvote it!

Comment: @filbranden It is certainly a better solution, however, OP described additional constraints. If you cannot actually copy a binary or install the executable, then it is difficult to suggest an external tool as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to compose the two commands using the `|` operator:

```
:%s/\(.\{-}{\)\(.\{-}\)\(}\)/\1\r\t\2\r\3\r/gc|%s/;/;\r\t/gc
```

Comment: Note that _this is not a unix pipe_. It’s a command separator, and there are cases where using it gets tricky (_e.g._, with `!`). So really, I would avoid the word pipe altogether.